# Limits of integration of cylindrical coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry

Given the volume V of integration
$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: 0 \le x^2+y^2 \le z \le 1\}$$

If I use the cylindrical coordinates substitution
$x=\rho\cos\theta$,
$y=\rho\sin\theta$ and $z=z$, what I get is $$V'=\{(\rho,\theta,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:0 \le \rho^2 \le z \le 1\}$$
But now, is $\rho$ between $0$ and $1$ or is it between $0$ and $\sqrt{z}\ $?

And what about $z$? Is it between $0$ and $1$ or $\rho^2$ and $1\ $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the order of integration.

If the $dz$ integral is outside the $d\rho$ integral, then the $z$ bounds must be constant (so $0$ and $1$), while the $\rho$ bounds must be in terms of $z$ (so $0$ and $\sqrt{z}$).

If, on the other hand, the $d\rho$ integral is outside the $dz$ integral, then the $\rho$ bounds must be constant (so $0$ and $1$), while the $z$ bounds must be in terms of $\rho$ (so $\rho^2$ and $1$).

Try both ways and check that you get the same answer!